# Maintaining the value of 'this' when using event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, event-listener

I have the following function:

```
onDocumentKeyUp: function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
       this.deactivate();
    }
}
```

I wanted to bind this like so:

```
$(document).on('keyup', onDocumentKeyUp);
```

However, when I do that, the `this` inside the `onDocumentKeyUp` function refers to the document. I solved this by doing:

```
var self = this;
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) { self.onDocumentKeyUp(e); });
```

This works, but something tells me there's a cleaner way to pull this off. Would `.call()` or `.apply()` somehow..apply here? I'm still unsure how those functions work exactly.

Also, I don't necessarily need to limit myself to `jQuery.on()`. If there is a 'vanilla' way of doing this, be my guest to teach me.

Comment: You mean like?                                                        
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) { onDocumentKeyUp.call(self, e); });

Comment: Could do, but it doesn't feel much cleaner to me. I want to know if there is a clean, idiomatic way to pass the value of this with the eventhandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your attention on `data` parameter of the `on` method here: http://api.jquery.com/on/
Also you can utilize jQuery.proxy method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Here is jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1stein/h3CTK/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context (without immediately calling it like `call` or `apply`):

```
$(document).on('keyup', this.onDocumentKeyUp.bind(this));
```

As this method is only supported by ES5.1-compliant browsers, you might use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) instead of polyfilling it.